# Two separate linear models

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, missing-data

I am trying to fit the following linear model:

```
funding.amount.received ~  borrower.age + borrower.doctoral.college.prestige.score + borrower.covar1 + borrower.covar2 + borrower.covar3
```

About 1/5th of the borrower's did not attend any doctorate programme. So their college prestige score is coded as `NA`. If I understand correctly, when one fits a linear model, these data rows with `NA` in `borrower.college.doctoral.prestige.score` gets excluded. Is there any way one can fit a linear model without deleting these informative data? Is fitting two separate linear models the only option? If so, can one integrate the results from two models?

Comment: Apart from imputation, can't do that with a linear model, you may try some different model which works with missing data, if it serves your purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You can use multiple imputation to impute the missing covariate data, under the missing at random assumption, and then perform the analysis. In R this can be easily done with the [**mice**](https://cran.r-project.org/package=mice) package that performs multiple imputation using the fully conditional specification approach. Another option is also to use sequential imputation that is performed by the [**JointAI**](https://cran.r-project.org/package=JointAI) package and in this instance by function `lm_imp()`.

Comment: I wasn't aware that imputation was a good choice for this situation. I will explore this. Any specific conceptual/implementation example you could point to would be very helpful. Thank you.